# how to get around DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user? my try and catch arent working

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

so I have a warning system for my discord bot. when I give someone a warning it DMs them the reason they got warned for and in what guild, however there's the exception of users who are unable to receive DMs at all. I want it to send the message "I couldn't DM this user but...." whenever there's that exception. I've tried "try catch" but I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

here's the code where the try and catch is happening:

```
try{
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`✅ **${target} has been warned || ${reason}**`)
  .setColor('#004d00')
  message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
  const embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`you were warned in ${guild} for: ${reason}`)
  .setColor('#b30000')
  user.send({ embeds: [embed2] })
} 
catch(error){
  const embed3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`✅ I Couldn't DM them but **${target} has been warned || ${reason}**`)
  .setColor('#004d00')
  message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed3] });
}
```

and here's all the code altogether altho it wouldn't make much difference I believe:

```
   const mongo = require('../mongo.js')
    const warnSchema = require('../schemas/warn-schema.js')
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    
    module.exports = {
      commands: 'warn',
      minArgs: 2,
      expectedArgs: "<Target user's @> <reason>",
      requiredRoles: ['Staff'],
      callback: async (message, arguments) => {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(arguments[0])
        if (!target) {
          message.channel.send('Please specify someone to warn.')
          return
        }
        const { guild, channel } = message
        arguments.shift()
    
        const guildId = message.guild.id
        const userId = target.id
        const reason = arguments.join(' ')
        const user = target
        const warning = {
          author: message.member.user.tag,
          timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
          reason,
        }
    
        await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
          try {
            await warnSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
              {
                guildId,
                userId,
              },
              {
                guildId,
                userId,
                $push: {
                  warnings: warning,
                },
              },
              {
                upsert: true,
              }
            )
          } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close()
          }
        })
        message.delete()
        try{
          const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setDescription(`✅ **${target} has been warned || ${reason}**`)
          .setColor('#004d00')
          message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
          const embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setDescription(`you were warned in ${guild} for: ${reason}`)
          .setColor('#b30000')
          user.send({ embeds: [embed2] })
        } 
        catch(error){
          const embed3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setDescription(`✅ I Couldn't DM them but **${target} has been warned || ${reason}**`)
          .setColor('#004d00')
          message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed3] });
        }
      },

}
```

Comment: `send` returns a promise, so you need to `await`. If the promise is rejected, await would throw and your catch should trigger.

Comment: omg thank you so much!!